# (wx)Maxima: apply scalar function to all elements of a list

Tags: list, function, maxima, wxmaxima

Currently, if I want to apply the transformation effected by a function of a single variables `f` to all values in a list, I use `makelist`, *e.g.*

```
f(x):= x^2;
aList: [1,2,3,4];
f_aList: makelist(f(aList[i]), i, length(aList));
```

I have to do this so often that I was about to write a quick function that would handle this, *e.g.*

```
apply2list(f, aList):=
   block([f:f, aList:aList],
   makelist(f(aList[i]), i, length(aList))
   );
```

for any single variable function `f` and list `aList`, but wondered if there was some way of doing this, already built in?

Comment: I think maybe you mean: `map(f, aList)`

Comment: I can only laugh at the many hours I have lost not knowing this. Thanks Robert :)

Comment: Haha, yeah that's my life with computers in a nutshell !